# Fiddler Not Capturing Traffic from my C# Application

Tags: c#, .net, fiddler

I am having problems capturing traffic sent and received from my C# application.

The application is an ordinary WinForms application using C# 5.0 and .NET 4.5. .

Fiddler captures traffic from Chrome and Firefox with no issues, just not my application. I have also loaded another application that I developed, and that works fine.

It may be worth noting that this is the first application I've developed that uses `HttpClient` to make Http requests. Could that be causing any issues?

To be clear the Fiddler Application monitors the traffic. I am not connecting to localhost. I am connect to web API's.

Comment: Are you connecting to localhost?

Comment: Have you checked that help page: http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/MonitorLocalTraffic

Comment: Do you use the Fiddler application to capture the traffic of your app, or do you use the Fiddler C# lib from your app?

Comment: I am not connecting to local host. I use the Fiddler application to capture traffic.

Comment: @kol I am using a WinForms app, not a metro style app.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Step #1 is to try starting Fiddler before starting your application. This helps the default configuration, whereby .NET applications pick up the system proxy when they start and are oblivious to proxy changes after they start.

Step #2, if the first step doesn't work, is to explicitly configure your process to use the proxy by editing the app.exe.config file or the machine.config file, or by setting the `Proxy` property on the request object.

Comment: How to edit the machine.config for .NET services - http://www.telerik.com/blogs/capturing-traffic-from-.net-services-with-fiddler

Comment: How do you do step 2? How do you identify the proxy?

Comment: Fiddler is a proxy running by default on port `8888` on your local PC (`localhost` or `127.0.0.1`)

Comment: I added this to my app.config file:

<system.net>
   <defaultProxy>
     <proxy usesystemdefault="False" bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>

Sorry, it doesn't preserve my formatting in here, but you can probably figure it out.  It goes just inside of <Configuration>.

Comment: I added this in app.config and ran application. Still fiddler is not capturing traffic raised by my application. If I visit my api from browser it does. Any clue?

Comment: Added in machine.config but its not capturing it, I am debugging application in VS2015